# Add url from metadata in vuforia

Tags: android, url, video, metadata, vuforia

I am trying to play video from metadata of `Vuforia` Cloud after successful image detection. But on giving link of metadata, the application crashes.

I followed all the steps.

I want to play a video from URL by using the `Vuforia` Android Native API.

I have changed the code in the *VideoPlayback* sample, as shown below. I get metadata as:

```
if (finder.getResultCount() > 0)
        {
            TargetSearchResult result = finder.getResult(0);
             metaResult = result.getMetaData();
            Toast.makeText(this,  metaResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The link in metadata is showing correctly in Toast.

In `VideoPlayback.java` class

```
//Video from Url
mMovieName[one]       = video;
```

I removed some code from `VideoPlayerHelper.java` as shown below:

```
//for Video from Url, in Load method
AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    afd.close();
```

Added:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
```

And removing the code

```
try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
    afd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "File does not exist");
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
    return false;
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
08-25 13:39:12.102 31380-1054/com.vuforia.samples.VideoPlayback E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 8377
                                                                                  Process: com.vuforia.samples.VideoPlayback, PID: 31380
                                                                                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
                                                                                      at java.util.Vector.arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(Vector.java:907)
                                                                                      at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:328)
                                                                                      at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:442)
                                                                                      at com.vuforia.samples.VideoPlayback.app.VideoPlayback.VideoPlaybackRenderer.renderFrame(VideoPlaybackRenderer.java:762)
                                                                                      at com.vuforia.samples.VideoPlayback.app.VideoPlayback.VideoPlaybackRenderer.onDrawFrame(VideoPlaybackRenderer.java:292)
                                                                                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
                                                                                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

What I am doing wrong? Also when I give direct link to `mMovie[one]="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";` the video is played perfectly but it not getting same link through metadata.